# How to display a barecode dynamically in a django template?

Tags: django-views, django-templates

I have a function that allows the user to generate an invoice in pdf and at the same time transform the reference of the invoice and save it in a subfolder of the media folder. When the pdf file is displayed, all the information of the selected invoice appear except the bar code which is important for me for each invoice.
I would like to know how can we display this bar code already saved in the media/code_barre folder dynamically when opening the pdf file?
Here is the template code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load mathfilters %}
{% load static %}
{% load custom_filters %}
{% load humanize %}
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Détails de la facture {{ invoice.reference }}</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        .header {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .navire-info {
            width: 50%;
        }
        .invoice-info {
            width: 50%;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .details {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd; /* Réduire l'épaisseur de la bordure */
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
            border-collapse: collapse; /* Pour que les bordures ne se chevauchent pas */
        }
        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        .prestation {
            width: 40%;
        }
        .date-operation,
        {
            width: 16%;
        }
        .total-ht,
        .taxe,
        .total-ttc {
            width: 15%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="navire-info">
            <h2>AGENCE: {{ invoice.navire.Agence.nom_Agence }}</h2>
            <p>Navire: {{ invoice.navire.nom_navire }}</p>
            <p>Immatriculation: {{ invoice.navire.IMO }}</p>
            <p>Volume du navire: {{ invoice.navire.longueur|mul:invoice.navire.largeur|mul:invoice.navire.tirant_d_eau|floatformat:2 }} m³</p>
        </div>
        <div class="invoice-info">
            <h1 class="">Détails de la facture </h1>
            <img src="{{ barcode_image_path }}" alt="Barcode" height="100px" width="250px">
            <p>Numéro de la facture: {{ invoice.reference }}</p>
            <p>Date de facturation: {{ invoice.date_facture }}</p>
            <p>Statut: {{ invoice.statut }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-striped custom-table datatable mb-0" border='1' style="line-height: 0.5;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="prestation">Prestations</th>
                <th class="date-operation">Date/Heure Op</th>
                <th class="total-ht">Total HT</th>
                <th class="taxe">Taxe(10%)</th>
                <th class="total-ttc">Total TTC</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for item in invoice.items.all %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.prestation }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.date_operation|date:'d/m/Y' }} {{ item.heure_operation }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.total_cost|calculate_amount_without_tax:invoice.TC|floatformat:2 }} KMF</td>
                <td>{{ item.total_cost|calculate_tax_amount:invoice.TC|floatformat:2 }} KMF</td>
                <td>{{ item.total_cost|intcomma:4 }} KMF</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" align="right">Montant initiale: {{ initial_amount|intcomma:2 }} KMF</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" align="right">Remise ({{ invoice.discount|calculate_discount_rate:total_cost_sum|floatformat:0 }}%): {{ invoice.discount|intcomma:2 }} KMF</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" align="right">Total à payer: {{ amount_after_discount|intcomma:2 }} KMF</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <p><b>Cette facture est arrêtée à la somme de {% convertir_en_lettres amount_after_discount %} franc(s) comorien(s).</b></p>

    <br>
    <div style="text-align: right; margin-top: 30px;">
        <p>Signature du chef de service : __________________________</p>
        <p>Date : {% now 'd/m/Y' %}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my views that is generating the barecode and the pfd file.

```
@login_required(login_url='/account/signin')
def invoice_detail_pdf(request, invoice_id):
    invoice = INVOICE.objects.get(id=invoice_id)

    # Calculate the total cost for all items related to this invoice
    total_cost_sum = invoice.items.aggregate(Sum('total_cost'))['total_cost__sum']

    # Check if the request is a POST request to handle the discount form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        discount_form = DiscountForm(request.POST)
        if discount_form.is_valid():
            discount_percentage = discount_form.cleaned_data['discount_percentage']
            # Calculate and apply the discount amount to the invoice
            discount_amount = (total_cost_sum * discount_percentage) / 100
            invoice.discount_amount = discount_amount
            invoice.save()

            # Redirect back to the same invoice detail page
            return redirect('invoice_detail', invoice_id=invoice_id)
    else:
        discount_form = DiscountForm()

    # Calculate the initial amount (without discount)
    initial_amount = total_cost_sum

    # Calculate the amount after the discount
    amount_after_discount = total_cost_sum - invoice.discount

   # Generate barcode
    barcode_value = str(invoice.reference)
    barcode_class = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
    barcode_image = barcode_class(barcode_value, writer=ImageWriter())
    
    # Modify the barcode image path to save it in the 'static' directory
    barcode_image_path = os.path.join('code_barre', f'{invoice.reference}.png')
    barcode_image.save(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, barcode_image_path))

    context = {
        'invoice': invoice,
        'discount_form': discount_form,
        'total_cost_sum': total_cost_sum,
        'initial_amount': initial_amount,
        'amount_after_discount': amount_after_discount,
        'barcode_image_path': barcode_image_path,  # Use 'static' to generate the URL
    }


    # Render the invoice template with the invoice details
    pdf = render_to_pdf('CENTRE_POLYVALENT/invoice_template.html', context)
    if pdf:
        response= HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="invoice_{}.pdf"'.format(invoice.reference)
        return response
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Fichier n'existe pas")
    return response
```

Just to display the generated barecode it the invoice pdf.

Thanks